# How to get _logical_ acquire- / release-barriers with g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I've got some code that employs __sync_val_compare_and_swap with my cross-platform shared_mutex-implementation. The Windows-version (#ifdef'd) uses the _InterlockedCompareExchange-intrinsic which has full physical (to the ordering of loads and stores by the cpu) and logical (to the compiler) acquire- and release-behaviour. I don' find any documentation that the __sync_val_compare_and_swap-intrinsic also has some logical effects on the ordering of loads and stores to the compiler. So is there any "intrinsic" that forces the compiler to have *logical* a acquire- or release barrier? I know there's `asm volatile("" ::: "memory");` with gcc, but this has acquire- and release-behaviour as well.

Comment: Do you *have* to use intrinsics rather than standard machinery (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)?

Comment: These intrinsics result in logical as well as physical barriers. I.e. on x86/AMD64 you'll get a "XCHG [mem], reg]" as a _physical_ barrier-instruction when using f.e. memory_order::acquire or memory_order::release.

Comment: Instead of using the (now-deprecated) __sync functions, how about using the [atomics](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#g_t_005f_005fatomic-Builtins)?  They allow you to specify acquire and release.

Comment: `as some logical effects on the ordering of loads and stores to the compiler`. Can you please define, what is a "logical effect" on the compiler? You mean that the compiler will not reorder and not optimize the code with __sync_val_compare_and_swap?

Comment: It is unspecified if __sync_val_compare_and_swap adds a barrier to loads and stores before and after the intrinsic to the compiler. So I need an intrinsic or whatever to have a barrier with either acquire- or consume-behaviour.